# How do I get an expanded sparse tree?

Tags: org-mode

I want to show all entries with status WAIT along with their parent entries and hide everything else.

```
#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t) WAIT(w) | DONE(d) PASS(p)
* Item
  Description.
** TODO Task 1
   Description.
** WAIT Task 2
   Description.
* Item
** WAIT Task 3
   Description.
```

If I do `C-c / m TODO="WAIT"` I get

```
#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t) WAIT(w) | DONE(d) PASS(p)
* Item...
** WAIT Task 2...
* Item
** WAIT Task 3...
```

As you can see the entries are collapsed. How do I get an expanded view of the selected entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify the variable, `org-show-context-detail`. `C-h v org-show-context-detail` will offer you *quite* a lot of documentation about the values this variable can take; the pertinent information is that it's an alist of `(context-symbol . visibility-symbol)`. You probably want to set it in your `init.el` / `.emacs.d` / other-config-file like so:

```
(push '(tags-tree . local) org-show-context-detail)
```

`tags-tree` is the context symbol for sparse trees (used also for todo statuses); `local` will show you `current headline, entry, and next headline`.