# org mode: expand all headings that match a search

Tags: org-mode

How can I expand all the headings with a name matching a search term?  For example, take the following fully expanded document:

```
* Famous Animals
** Pigs
   - Ace
   - Babe
** Cats
   - Duchess
   - Felix
* Musical Characters
** Cats
   - Demeter
   - Macavity
** Chicago
   - Roxie
   - Velma
```

Now let's collapse it completely:

```
* Famous Animals
* Musical Characters
```

I'd like to be able to search for "Cats" and get the following headings to expand:

```
* Famous Animals
** Pigs
** Cats
   - Duchess
   - Felix
* Musical Characters
** Cats
   - Demeter
   - Macavity
** Chicago
```

Extra points if I can do an incremental search and have the headings expand as I type.

Answer (score 1):

`org-sparse-tree` (<kbd>C-c /</kbd>) does exactly what you want.

For example, <kbd>C-c / / Cats RET</kbd> will expand all content where "Cats" appears, and collapse the rest.

Comment: It's very close.  It shows the "Cats' heading, but unless I'm doing it wrong, it doesn't show the lists under "Cats".  Is there any way to expand them further?

Comment: I also tried applying the answer here to no avail: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15109/how-do-i-get-an-expanded-sparse-tree/18477

Comment: @oneself does: `(add-to-list 'org-show-context-detail '(occur-tree . local))` work for you? It won't show the siblings I think.

Comment: Yes, it that works perfectly. Thank you!